# Typescript, Class has no index signature

Tags: typescript

A simple implementation of the my code is like this:

```
interface IndexSignature{
  [key:string]:any;
}
class Foo implements IndexSignature{
  bar(){};
  baz(){
    this['bar'](); //Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Foo' has no index signature.
  }
}
```

how can I add index signature to the Foo class?

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement the indexer defined in the interface

```
interface IndexSignature {
  [key: string]: any;
}
class Foo implements IndexSignature {
  [key: string]: any;
  bar() { };
  baz() {
    this['bar']();
    let something = this["something"]; // throws before indexer implementation, no longer throws
  }
}
```

Your example actually does not throw an error even without the indexer implementation because `Foo` has member `bar` which can be used with the index notation without defining an indexer.

Comment: I think too that in my example it should not throw error but it does! `error TS7017`

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: version : 2.1.5

Comment: yes with gulp-typescript and also phpstrom typescript plugin.

Comment: Not with an IDE. Are you able to compile by running `tsc` from the command line? Also post your tsconfig.json

Comment: is there any way to avoid the "any"? I want to define an index signature like this: "[key:string]: string", but then I can't add method to the class.